# Recyclerview inside a Fragment which is inside BottomsheetFragment not scrolling?

Tags: android, android-fragments, scroll, bottom-sheet, android-nestedscrollview

I have a BottomsheetDialogFragment which has a normal Fragment which has a recyclerview. The problem is I am not able to scroll the recyclerview.

I thought of using the NestedScrollView but I have a search functionality inside the fragment. When the Keypad pops up, its working fine but as soon as the keypad hide the transition of the bottomsheet coming down is not okay. So, i am not able to use that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/whitebackground"


    android:focusable="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/whitebackground"
        >



    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And at runtime i am inflating the layout which contains the recyclerview.

Comment: Have you tried making "fillviewport" attribute of scrollview to be true and cause the recyclerview to enable nestedscrolling ? 
using this line right after you set recyclerview adapter
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);

Comment: Have you tried validating your relative layout after adding recyclerview?

Comment: Can you define what is `not okay`? A video would be helpful.

Comment: I have manged to do the scrolling part but now the new error comes. I have set the height of the recyclerview around 500dp. There is a space at the bottom and the recyclerview is shifter up to the top of the screen.

Comment: @Sniper hey, please share your solution or please provide feedback to the answers. Otherwise whoever visits this question will go empty hand. Community trying to help you, please help back.

Answer (score 2):

You can use isNestedScrollingEnabled property inside a fragment or activity.

```
recyclerOuter.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to intercept touch event for recyclerview rather than BottomSheet layout.
Default when you touch to scroll the event triggers in bottomsheet layout not on recyclerview. Use below code to intercept the touch event for recyclerview forcefully

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewNotes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


recyclerViewNotes?.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
            v.onTouchEvent(event)
            true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_350sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_shapee"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_70sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <com.mydroid.svg.print.craft.design.graphic.sticker.a_editScreen.viewPager.BottomSheetViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:theme="@style/CustomBottomSheetDialog"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="160dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:tabIndicator="@null"
                android:theme="@style/TabLayout_Theme"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
                app:tabMinWidth="@dimen/_100sdp"
                app:tabMaxWidth="@dimen/_100sdp"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_shape"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabTextColor="?colorOnSurface"
                app:tabRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"/>

        </com.mydroid.svg.print.craft.design.graphic.sticker.a_editScreen.viewPager.BottomSheetViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**strong text**

Answer (score -1):

Since your problem starting with the keyboard you can try to add following line to activity definition in your AndroidManifest.xml. This line will make sure when the keyboard pops up your view will not resize.
`<activity...
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
.../>`

And you should add to your coordinator layout
`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`